# CharacterPointer in C++

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
char* foo(char* str1)
{  
    str1 = "Some other text";
    cout << "String Inside Function::" << str1 << endl;

    return str1;
}

int main()
{  
    char* str = "This is a string";

    cout << "String Before Function call::" << str << endl;
    foo(str);
    cout<<"String After Function call::"<<str<<endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But the `cout` after my function call gives me "This is a string" even though I have changed it in my `foo` function. I'm confused here although I know it has got something to do with me not passing the correct address.

Comment: Everything except for references are passed by value in C++, including pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Adding & (aka pass by reference) after the char* you can modify the pointer that you passed into foo function
// but you must understand that it was another place in memory!!!
void foo(char*& str1)
{  
    // This string saved in global section and here you
    // changed not the text in the str1 but the pointer itself
    str1 = "Some other text"; 
    cout << "String Inside Function::" << str1 << endl;
}

// Another way to change pointer itself is pass a pointer to the pointer
void foo_v2(char** str1)
{
    // You should dereference pointer to pointer (* before str1)
    *str1 = "Some other text";
}

// In this case you change the content at the pointer str1
// It very dangerous, you can replace content not only the memory under str1
// but even return address if string placed in stack memory.
// Such terrible things occurred if your string that copied into str1 
// occupied more bytes then it can be contained in str1
// More safe way is using for example std::string
void foo2(char* str1)
{    
     char *s = "Some other text";
     strcpy(str1, s, strlen(s));
}

int main()
{  
    char* str = "This is a string";

    cout << "String Before Function call::" << str << endl;
    foo(str);
    cout<<"String After Function call::"<<str<<endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are changing the pointers value and not what it points to.

Comment: Replace the input Parameter to a reference like char*& p_char.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a pointer by copy, the function you call gets a copy of that pointer, just as passing by copy of any other type means you can't modify the original, passing by pointer works in the same way.

```
void f(char* copy)
{
    // the copy here is modified to point to test
    copy = "Test";       
}

void g(char* copy)
{
   g[0] = 'C';
}

int main()
{
   char* p = nullptr;

   // f gets a copy of p, p cannot be modified by f
   f(p);

   char p2[5] = "copy";

   // g gets a copy of p2, the value of p2 (the pointer) cannot be modified by g
   // however, g can modify what p2 points to
   g(p2);

   // prints "Copy" (not "copy")
   cout << p2;
}
```

If you want to change what a pointer "points to" via a function, you have to do that in the same way that you would change any other type passed to a function.  Either through a pointer (double pointer in this case) or reference (preferred).

```
void make_c(char** c)
{
   *c = new char[10];
}

void make_c(char*& c)
{
   c = new char[10];
}

int main()
{
   char* t = nullptr;

   // via pointer (double pointer in this case)
   make_c(&t);

   delete [] t;

   // via reference
   make_c(t);

   delete [] t;
}
```